# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to get a CoffeeScript class to extend a Backbone.Model.  I built a brand new rails 3.1 app, created a scaffold of 'Stone', with 3 attributes, and patched a snippet of the Todos.coffee example into stones.js.coffee.  I have both backbone.js and underscore.js in the app/assets/javascripts folder.  When I run this under the Chrome Java console, I get the message above in the console log.  Any ideas?

Actual code follows:

```
$ -> 

  class Todo extends Backbone.Model
    # Default attributes for the todo.
    defaults:
     content: "empty todo..."
     done: false

    # Ensure that each todo created has `content`.
    initialize: ->
      if !@get("content")
      @set({ "content": @defaults.content })

    # Toggle the `done` state of this todo item.
    toggle: ->
      @save({ done: !@get("done") })

    # Remove this Todo from *localStorage* and delete its view.
    clear: ->
      @destroy()
      @view.remove()
```

The application.js being used is what was generated by Rails 3.1.  I copied the backbone.js and underscore.js from the Todos github repo, https://github.com/JasonGiedymin/backbone-todojs-coffeescript

Comment: Make sure backbone.js and underscore.js are actually being added to the page. If you're in development evironment you should be able to view the source and see wether or not they are being included.

Can you paste your application.js or whichever manifest file you're using in this view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is simply that `underscore.js` is being loaded after `backbone.js`, when it's a prereq that has to be loaded before. (Notice in the [Backbone.js source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) that it sets `var _ = root._` immediately, so even if a global `_` is declared later, it's not visible from Backbone's scope.) Sprockets loads the JS files in your assets directory in alphabetical order by default.

You can fix this using Sprockets: Put

```
//= require underscore.js
```

before

```
//= require_tree .
```

to ensure that it's loaded first.