# TypeError: Backbone.Router is undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I've been working through a wonderful set of tutorials by [Derick Bailey](http://www.watchmecode.net/) and ran into an issue with adding a Router. in IE it describes the error as : SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'extend': object is null or undefined (in IE)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined (in Chrome)

I did read this question : [uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-extend-of-undefined
The code in question is here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762169/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-extend-of-undefined), but I did verify that underscore was loaded in the html of the page via HTTPWatch. Also, about 100 lines earlier in the same file, I invoke underscore for another method. Code is spot on with what is in the tutorial as far as I can tell.

```
ImageGallery.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "images/:id": "showImage"
},
initialize: function (options) {
    this.collection = options.collection;
},
showImage: function (id) {
    var image = this.collection.get(id);
    ImageGallery.showImage(image);
}
```

});

Any insights would be appreciated.

I put the rest of the backbone code on JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/poundingCode/4ekU3/ b/c it was too hard to format.

Comment: Are you really using version 0.3.3 (http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js) of Backbone? I think Backbone.Router used to be called something else.

Comment: Yeah, looks like Backbone was using `Backbone.Controller` instead of `Backbone.Router` way back in the 0.3.3 days. Upgrade to the latest versions of Backbone and Underscore and you'll have a better time.

Comment: I confirmed that I'm using http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"  http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"

Comment: Figured it out, thanks to your input - turns out I was using the CDN version of the libraries & the tutorial was using local versions, don't know why that would make a difference, but that resolved the issue.